# Error 403 when I submit to add a new message

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am learning spring boot and write a small project form. I run it in idea and submit the form,registrtion works but when i'm truing to add new message, the browser occurs

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Forbidden, status=403).
```

Forbidden

i tried to add a new functional, i want that it will show also a name of user, but doesn't work

This is a Message class

```
@Entity
public class Message {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String text;
    private String tag;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User author;


    public Message() {
    }

    public Message(String text, String tag, User user) {
        this.author=user;
        this.text = text;
        this.tag = tag;
    }

    public String getAuthorName(){
        return author !=null ? author.getUsername() : "<nine>";
    }

    public User getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(User author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getTag() {
        return tag;
    }

    public void setTag(String tag) {
        this.tag = tag;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Controller

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

    @Autowired
    private MessasgeRepo messasgeRepo;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String greeting(Model model) {

        return "greeting";
    }

    @GetMapping("/main")
    public String main(Model model){
        Iterable<Message> messages = messasgeRepo.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("mess",messages);
        return "main";
    }

    @PostMapping("/main")
    public String add (@AuthenticationPrincipal User user,
                       @RequestParam String text,
                       @RequestParam String tag, Model model){
        Message message =new Message(text, tag, user);
        messasgeRepo.save(message);
        Iterable<Message> messages = messasgeRepo.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("mess",messages);
        return "main";
    }

    @PostMapping("filter")
    public String filter(@RequestParam String text, Model model){
        Iterable<Message> messages;
        if(text!=null && !text.isEmpty()) {
            messages = messasgeRepo.findByTag(text);
        }else {
            messages = messasgeRepo.findAll();
        }
        model.addAttribute("mess", messages);
        return "main";
    }
}
```

and html document

```html
<div>
<form method="post">
    <input type="text"  name="text" placeholder="Enter first name"  >
    <input type="text" name="tag" placeholder="Enter first name" >
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"> Add order</button>
</form>
</div>

<form method="post" action="/filter">
    <input type="text" name="text">
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
    <p>Message</p>
<div th:each="me : ${mess}" >
    <b th:text="${me.id}"/>
    <span th:text="${me.text}"/>
    <i th:text="${me.tag}"/>
    <strong th:text="${me.authorName}"/>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think action `action="/main"` is missing here, try below code

```
<form method="post" action="/main">
<input type="text"  name="text" placeholder="Enter first name">
<input type="text" name="tag" placeholder="Enter first name">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"> Add order </button>
</form>
```